# Azure Function Cron expression for excluding a defined time

Tags: azure, cron, azure-functions

I want to do very basic cron job on Azure Function.
I'm writing functions on Visual Studio and the functions will be dockerized job.
There are two different azure function on my solution.

1. Runs for every month. (Refreshes whole table).
2. Runs for every five minutes. (Refhreshes just feature records. Not historical records.)

My expectation is that the functions shouldn't block eachother. So, they shouldn't work at the same time.
My cron expressions for the functions are;

- **Function1**: 0 0 0 1 * * (Runs every month on 1st.)
- **Function2**: 0 */5 * * * * (Runs every five minutes)

I don't want to run function2 on every month like 01/01/2021 00:00:00.
How can I exclude the time from function2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to do that.

As a workaround, you can add `if else` code block in Function2. For example, in the `if block`, you can determine if it's the time like `01/01/2021 00:00:00`. if yes, then do nothing. If not, then go to the `else block` to execute your logic.

Like below:

```
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    var the_time = DateTime.Now;

    //if the date is the first day of a month, and time is 00:00:00
    if(the_time.Day==1 && the_time.ToLongTimeString().Contains("00:00:00"))
    {
      //do nothing, don't write any code here.
    }
    else
   {
      //write your code logic here
   }

}
```

Comment: Yes this is a way to handle that. As there is no way to define as a cron expression directly, I have to do this solution.Thank you.